# Variable Polyline Weight with GEOJSON in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, polyline

**Here is the entire HTML document:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Top 5 Importers of Tungsten</title>

    <!--Imports stylesheet from Leaflet --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
     <!-- Import jQuery, a common JavaScript library providing hundreds of functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Planewalker;
            src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3hn6zi8ez2vf4d7/Planewalker.ttf');
        }

        a:link{text-decoration: none;color:#0000FF;}
        a:visited{text-decoration:none;color:#0000FF;}
        a:hover{color:#990000;text-decoration:none;}

        #map {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 600px;
            border: black solid 2px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #map2 {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 550px;
            border: black solid 2px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #map3 {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 550px;
            border: black solid 2px;
            display: block;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        .info {
            padding: 6px 8px;
            font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .info h4 {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            color: #777;
        }

        .legend {
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #555;
        }

        .legend i {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        #header{
            width:450px;
            border-radius:15px;
            background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/j1ii4yz5qftrks7/greyscale-natural-grunge-textures-6.jpg);
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            border: black solid 2px; 
            font-size: 40px;
            padding-top: 7px;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            padding-left: 12px;
            padding-right: 12px;
        }

        body{
            font-family: "Planewalker", "Lucida Sans Unicode","Arial",sans-serif; 
            background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2m8803ulxv2mcfc/footer_lodyas.png);
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        #footer{
            text-align: right; 
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }   

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><span style="color:#fbf400;">T</span><span style="color:#faf612;">o</span><span style="color:#f9f824;">p</span><span style="color:#f8fa36;"> </span><span style="color:#f8fb48;">5</span><span style="color:#f7fd5a;"> </span><span style="color:#f6ff6c;">T</span><span style="color:#f8ff85;">u</span><span style="color:#f9ff9d;">n</span><span style="color:#fbffb6;">g</span><span style="color:#fcffce;">s</span><span style="color:#feffe7;">t</span><span style="color:#ffffff;">e</span><span style="color:#fdffe2;">n</span><span style="color:#fbffc4;"> </span><span style="color:#faffa7;">I</span><span style="color:#f8ff89;">m</span><span style="color:#f6ff6c;">p</span><span style="color:#f7fd5a;">o</span><span style="color:#f8fb48;">r</span><span style="color:#f9f936;">t</span><span style="color:#f9f824;">e</span><span style="color:#faf612;">r</span><span style="color:#fbf400;">s</span></div>

<!--DIV FOR IMPORT LINE MAP ("map")-->
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <br>
<!--DIV FOR CANADA MINES MAP-->
    <div id="map2" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 550px;"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a95n5ecg1a7j62i/canada_mine_map2.png" height="550" width="1000"></div>
    <br>
<!--DIV FOR CHINA MINES MAP-->
    <div id="map3" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 550px;"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/p2vf6q01ck0xt8r/china_province_output_map3.png" height="550" width="1000"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Imports a ColorBrewer library, containing many pre-designed color schemes -->
    <script src="colorbrewer.js"></script>
<!--GEOJSONS FOR IMPORT LINE MAP-->
    <script src="CHN_crossF.geojson"></script>
    <script src="DEU_crossF.geojson"></script>
    <script src="FRA_crossF.geojson"></script>
    <script src="JPN_crossF.geojson"></script>
    <script src="US_crossF.geojson"></script>

<!--IMPORT LINE MAP-->
    <script>

        var southWest = new L.LatLng(80, -900),
            northEast = new L.LatLng(-80, 900),
            bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            //can add "maxBounds: bounds" to stop the map at a certian point; add into L.map in the {}
        var map = L.map('map',{
            worldCopyJump:true,
            continuousWorld:false,
            noWrap:false,
            minZoom:3,
            inertia:false,
            maxBounds:bounds
            }).setView([35.460669951495305, -21.796875], 3); //Starting map location

        //Sets the basemap
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
        }).addTo(map);

    //WEIGHT & COLOR FOR CHINA
        function getStyle1(feature){
            var weight;
              if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

            return {
                color: 'red',
                weight: weight
              }
        };

        var CHNimports = L.geoJson(CHN, {
            style: getStyle1,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to China: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);

    //WEIGHT AND COLOR FOR GERMANY
        function getStyle2(feature){
            var weight;
              if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

            return {
                color: '#00FF00',
                weight: weight
              }
        };

        var DEUimports = L.geoJson(DEU, {
            style: getStyle2,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to Germany: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);

    //WEIGHT AND COLOR FOR FRANCE
        function getStyle3(feature){
                var weight;
                  if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

                return {
                    color: 'white',
                    weight: weight
                  }
        };

        var FRAimports = L.geoJson(FRA, {
            style: getStyle3,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to France: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);

    //WEIGHT AND COLOR FOR JAPAN
        function getStyle4(feature){
                var weight;
                  if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

                return {
                    color: 'yellow',
                    weight: weight
                  }
        };

        var JPNimports = L.geoJson(JPN, {
            style: getStyle4,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to Japan: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);

    //WEIGHT AND COLOR FOR US
        function getStyle5(feature){
                var weight;
                  if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
                  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

                return {
                    color: '#0000FF',
                    weight: weight
                  }
        };

        var USimports = L.geoJson(US, {
            style: getStyle5,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to US: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);

    //ICONS FOR COUNTRIES~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:
        //NORTH AMERICA POINTS
            var CANicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/North%20America%20-%20Mac/Canada.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([56.130366,-106.346771],{icon:CANicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Canada</b>");
            L.marker([56.130366,253.653229],{icon:CANicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Canada</b>");

            var USicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://static.wix.com/media/93cbc2_eaca32a202866ed8dd83758cc48a0385.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([37.09024,-95.712891],{icon:USicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>United States</b>");
            L.marker([37.09024,264.287109],{icon:USicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>United States</b>");

            var MEXicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/North%20America%20-%20Mac/Mexico.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([23.634501,-102.552784],{icon:MEXicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Mexico</b>");
            L.marker([23.634501,257.447216],{icon:MEXicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Mexico</b>");

        //SOUTH AMERICA POINTS
            var BOLicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.argenpapa.com.ar/images/paises/2.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-16.290154,-63.588653],{icon:BOLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Bolivia</b>");
            L.marker([-16.290154,296.411347],{icon:BOLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Bolivia</b>");

            var BRAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/flags-icons-by-wolfgang-bartelme/png/216/br.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-14.235004,-51.92528],{icon:BRAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Brazil</b>");
            L.marker([-14.235004,308.07472],{icon:BRAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Brazil</b>");

            var COLicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/rounded-world-flags/colombia-flag-1.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([4.570868,-74.297333],{icon:COLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Colombia</b>");
            L.marker([4.570868,285.702667],{icon:COLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Colombia</b>");

            var PERicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/south-america-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Peru.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-9.189967,-75.015152],{icon:PERicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Peru</b>");
            L.marker([-9.189967,284.984848],{icon:PERicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Peru</b>");

            var CHLicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/south-america-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Chile.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-35.675147,-71.542969],{icon:CHLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Chile</b>");
            L.marker([-35.675147,288.457031],{icon:CHLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Chile</b>");

        //EUROPE POINTS
            var PORicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/europe-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Portugal.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([39.399872,-8.224454],{icon:PORicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Portugal</b>");

            var ESPicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Europe/Spain.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([40.463667,-3.74922],{icon:ESPicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Spain</b>");

            var FRAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/656/rounded_world_flags/256/france.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([46.227638,2.213749],{icon:FRAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>France</b>");

            var DEUicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/flags-icons-by-wolfgang-bartelme/png/216/de.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([51.165691,10.451526],{icon:DEUicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Germany</b>");

            var GBRicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'https://www.railpol.eu/RailPol/fs3_site.nsf/fck_images/069634987717D7A8C1257A83004C7C92/$FILE/United%20Kingdom%20Flag.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([55.378051,-3.435973],{icon:GBRicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>United Kingdom</b>");

            var BELicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/656/rounded_world_flags/256/belgium.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([50.503887,4.469936],{icon:BELicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Belgium</b>");

            var TURicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-cons/world-flags-orbs-icons-by-vathanx/png/256/Flag%20of%20Turkey.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([38.963745,35.243322],{icon:TURicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Turkey</b>");

            var CHEicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/europe-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Switzerland.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([46.818188,8.227512],{icon:CHEicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Switzerland</b>");

            var ESTicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-cons/world-flags-orbs-icons-by-vathanx/png/256/Flag%20of%20Estonia.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([58.595272,25.013607],{icon:ESTicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Estonia</b>");

        //MIDDLE EAST ICONS
            var ISRicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/asia-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Israel.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([31.046051,34.851612],{icon:ISRicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Israel</b>");

        //AFRICA ICONS 
            var RWAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Africa/Rwanda.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-1.940278,29.873888],{icon:RWAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Rwanda</b>");

            var NGAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/africa-flags-icons-by-studiotwentyeight/png/256/Nigeria.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([9.081999,8.675277],{icon:NGAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Nigeria</b>");

            var BRIicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-cons/world-flags-orbs-icons-by-vathanx/png/256/Flag%20of%20Burundi.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-3.373056,29.918886],{icon:BRIicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Burundi</b>");

            var DZAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/internet-cons/world-flags-orbs-icons-by-vathanx/png/256/Flag%20of%20Algeria.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([28.033886,1.659626],{icon:DZAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Algeria</b>");

        //ASIA ICONS 
            var RUSicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/flags-icons-by-wolfgang-bartelme/png/216/ru.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([61.52401,105.318756],{icon:RUSicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Russia</b>");
            L.marker([61.52401,-254.681244],{icon:RUSicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Russia</b>");

            var CHNicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/China.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([35.86166,104.195397],{icon:CHNicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>China</b>");
            L.marker([35.86166,-255.804603],{icon:CHNicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>China</b>");

            var MONicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/Mongolia.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([46.862496,103.846656],{icon:MONicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Mongolia</b>");
            L.marker([46.862496,-256.153344],{icon:MONicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Mongolia</b>");

            var PHLicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/Philippines.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([12.879721,121.774017],{icon:PHLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Philippines</b>");
            L.marker([12.879721,-238.225983],{icon:PHLicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Philippines</b>");

            var MMRicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flag-icons/256/Flag_of_Burma_Myanmar.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([21.913965,95.956223],{icon:MMRicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Myanmar</b>");
            L.marker([21.913965,-264.043777],{icon:MMRicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Myanmar</b>");

            var VNMicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/Vietnam.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([14.058324,108.277199],{icon:VNMicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Vietnam</b>");
            L.marker([14.058324,-251.722801],{icon:VNMicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Vietnam</b>");

            var THAicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/Thailand.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([15.870032,100.992541],{icon:THAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Thailand</b>");
            L.marker([15.870032,-259.007459],{icon:THAicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Thailand</b>");

            var PRKicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/flags-icons-by-wolfgang-bartelme/png/216/kp.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([40.339852,127.510093],{icon:PRKicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Democratic People's Republic of Korea</b>")
            L.marker([40.339852,-232.489907],{icon:PRKicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Democratic People's Republic of Korea</b>")

            var KORicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/flags-icons-by-wolfgang-bartelme/png/216/kr.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([35.907757,127.766922],{icon:KORicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Republic of Korea</b>")
            L.marker([35.907757,-232.233078],{icon:KORicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Republic of Korea</b>")

            var JPNicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Asia/Japan.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([36.204824,138.252924],{icon:JPNicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Japan</b>")
            L.marker([36.204824,-221.747076],{icon:JPNicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Japan</b>")

        //AUSTRALIA ICONS 
            var AUSicon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/rounded-world-flags/australia-flag-2.png',
                iconSize: [35,35],
                iconAnchor: [17.5,17.5],
                });
            L.marker([-25.274398,133.775136],{icon:AUSicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Australia</b>")
            L.marker([-25.274398,-226.224864],{icon:AUSicon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("<b>Australia</b>")

        //Sets layer control
        var overlay_layers = {
            "Chinese Imports of Tungsten": CHNimports,
            "German Imports of Tungsten": DEUimports,
            "French Imports of Tungsten": FRAimports,
            "Japanese Imports of Tungsten": JPNimports,
            "United States Imports of Tungsten": USimports
        }
        L.control.layers(null, overlay_layers).addTo(map);

    </script>

<br>
<br>
    <p id="footer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

*Here is a dropbox link to the GEOJSONS if anyone would like to see them (hopefully this works as intended and people can download them)*:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4bi70dx2t99qgln/AABJfyNDJzgNTQK4Wu3vYnVRa?dl=0

I  have been working on a project to create a flowmap in Leaflet using GEOJSON polylines.  I have only recently become acquainted with JavaScript and Leaflet.  Here is an example of what I would like to make (my map uses rhumb lines and would be interactive):

[Flowmap Example](http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/hk/O1RiHZz0LGesvxrAKh6VQsIBKN/www.gislounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/us-trade-map.png.pagespeed.ce.lZRZHu5LCTsqwx1_gWqT.png)

Here is the updated and working function that changes the polyline weight based on its 'Value' from the GEOJSON file (credit to [Hinrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024590/hinrich) & [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209136/jonathan) for their help!):

```
function getStyle1(feature){
            var weight;
              if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 20;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 18;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 16;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 14;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 12;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 10;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 8;}
              else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 6;};

            return {
                color: 'red',
                weight: weight
              }
        };

        var CHNimports = L.geoJson(CHN, {
            style: getStyle1,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>"+"Import Partner: "+feature.properties.Partner+"</b>"+ "<br />Dollar value of imports to China: " + feature.properties.Value);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.polyline(latlng);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

<s>The lines vary by value and I will be able to change to color dependent on the country but the popup information does not appear when a polyline is clicked on</s>.

In addition, here is a sample of the GEOJSON file for CHNimports:

```
var CHN = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Partner":"Algeria","LongX":1.659626,"LatY":28.033886,"CHNLong":104.195397,"CHNLat":35.86166,"Value":587},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1.659626,28.033886],[1.669754918002165,28.034691811007274],[1.679883911463014,28.035497621919983],[1.690012980385739,28.036303432738126],[1.700142124773322,28.037109243461707],[1.710271344628953,28.03791505409072],[1.720400639955684,28.038720864625162],[1.730530010756992,28.039526675065034],[1.74065945703536,28.040332485410335],[1.750788978794404,28.041138295661067],[1.760918576037107,28.041944105817212],[1.771048248766518,28.042749915878783],[1.781177996986042,28.04355572584578],[1.791307820698163,28.044361535718185],[1.801437719906642,28.045167345496015],[1.811567694614244,28.045973155179254],[1.821697744824234,28.04677896476791],[1.831827870539733,28.04758477426198],[1.841958071763792,28.04839058366145],[1.852088348499675,28.04919639296634],[1.862218700750077,28.050002202176625], ...continued on
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you ask others to read and understand your code, proper code formatting would certainly be helpful. If you could manage to reduce your question to one specific problem you can't seem to solve, independent from your specific input,  this would also help to get more people to look at your question.

Comment: @ralfstx, Hopefully my edit is more along the lines of what you mean.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: If you posted your full script that would help a lot! Being able to see how you call getWeight(), what you are expecting to have returned, and how you access the GeoJSON file would all help!

Comment: I've added the entire HTML code to the post and I also included a dropbox link that has the GEOJSONS if they are needed.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve]; providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your function should actually return the weight. something more like this:

```
var getStyle = function(feature){
  var weight;
  if (feature.properties.Value > 30000000) {weight = 8;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 10000000) {weight = 7;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 5000000) {weight = 6;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000000) {weight = 5;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 500000) {weight = 4;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 100000) {weight = 3;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1000) {weight = 2;}
  else if (feature.properties.Value > 1) {weight = 1;};

  return {
    color: 'red',
    weight: weight
  }
};

var getPopup = function(feature, layer) {
  var content = 'popup content goes here';
  layer.bindPopup(content);
};
```

try this then for the styling and popup part:

```
var CHNimports = L.geoJson(CHN, { 
    style: getStyle,
    onEachFeature: getPopup
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I added this to the code but now the problem I have is that the polylines that are generated all have a weight of 1 and my popup information does not show up when the line is clicked on.

Comment: i updated my answer. see leaflet docs [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) for further reference

Comment: When I use the styling I get the error 'feature' is not defined.  This happens if I use the exact code you suggested or if I try to place it in my existing variable.

Comment: edited my answer again. can you show some sample of your geojson object, if this still fails?

Comment: What you submitted works to change the color and the weight of the lines!  Now the only problem I have is that I am unable to click on the polylines to display the popup information.  I've updated the original post to reflect the changes to the code/new problem.

Comment: Updated... You need to have just 1 object as argument for the L.geojson function, containing the relevant options

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you're calling `L.geoJson` with too many parameters.

Your code;

```
var CHNimports = L.geoJson(CHN, {style: getStyle}, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("Omitted for formatting...");
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.polyline(latlng);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

What it should look like, note the change to the `style` property;

```
var CHNimports = L.geoJson(CHN, {
    style: getStyle,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("Omitted for formatting...");
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.polyline(latlng);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The function `L.geoJson` only takes 2 arguments. The first is the geoJson object and the second is another json object that contains `style`, `onEachFeature` and `pointToLayer`.

Documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson